# python user name is not getting printed on console

Tags: python

I have got the answer my code was incorrectly indented. I was not calling function correctly

I am not getting any error or result in console.It should print mchaps as an user name

```
 class User:
    def SetUserName(self, userName):
        self._UserName = userName
    def GetUserName(self):
        return self._UserName


def main():
    u1 = User()
    u1.SetUserName('mchaps')
    print(u1.GetUserName())
    u2 = User()
    u2.SetUserName('chapsking')
    print(u2.GetUserName())

    if __name__ == '__main__':main()



    Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: You're never calling `main`. Python isn't C - it executes code line-by-line, from top to bottom, starting from the first line of the script, _not_ from `main`.

Comment: Sorry I missed the line I am calling main too. Please have a look i still get nothing. Check below.

class User:
    def SetUserName(self, userName):
        self._UserName = userName
    def GetUserName(self):
        return self._UserName


def main():
    u1 = User()
    u1.SetUserName('mchaps')
    print(u1.GetUserName())
    u2 = User()
    u2.SetUserName('chapsking')
    print(u2.GetUserName())

    if __name__ == '__main__':main()

Comment: Then your code is incorrectly indented. The line `if __name__ == '__main__':main()` is _inside_ `main`, and my previous comment still applies.

Comment: Thank you so much :). You are right my code was incorrectly indented. Now I have corrected it. silly mistake. Thanks again.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. The indentation of the code you shared here looks broken. Also, you don't need to write getters/setters like that, and variable and function names should follow the `lower_case_with_underscores` style.

Answer (score 0):

In principle you *could* append a line saying `main()` to your file.
But much better to habitually protect it with an `if`,
in case your module grows up one day to offer a valuable function
that some other file wants to `import`:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Also, [PEP-8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) asks that you spell it `set_user_name` and `get_user_name`.
You see, capitalization has meaning in python,
at least to human readers.

Comment: I have missed the last line of code in question if __name__ == '__main__':main() but it is there in my pycharm i still get nothing. No error no result

Comment: It's not clear that even a `print("hello world")` would produce output, in your PyCharm environment. Are you _sure_ the IDE is successfully running your favorite python interpreter? Try it from an interactive shell command line: `python user.py`. Or even more simply: `python -c "print('hello')"`

Answer (score 0):

You need to call the main method.

```py
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

you could also just call the main/remove the `def main()`

```py
class User:
    def SetUserName(self, userName):
        self._UserName = userName
    def GetUserName(self):
        return self._UserName


u1 = User()
u1.SetUserName('mchaps')
print(u1.GetUserName())
```

The `__name__ == "main"` checks if you ran the script itself. If you were to include the script in another script `__name__` would not be **main** thus it would not call the `main` method.

Comment: I have missed the last line of code in question if __name__ == '__main__':main() but it is there in my pycharm i still get nothing. No error no result